# handling different sized images in jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Hi Im using a standard jquery image slider/carousel to display images.

I have images of various sizes being used in the slider. How can I ensure the width and height dont affect the dimensions of the slider, whilst still looking half decent. eg slider is width= 300px  height = 200px?

I want it like the behaviour of this slider:
http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

but im not using this one as its not great for a responsive design

Comment: Have you seen this slider. It is built for responsive design. http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Comment: yes, I've seen this. the problem is scaling images to fit the container

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to make the slider placeholder as big as your largest image, or if you want them all the same size, set `width` and `height` attributes on the `<img>` tag to override the actual dimensions of the image.

If the ratio of width to height is not consistent then you may need to calculate the reduced dimensions on the fly, either on the server on in jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: The first option won't work as I cant deternmine what the diminsions will be. setting the width and height manually really messes up images when you have tall portrait images followed by wide landscape ones.

Comment: Yes, this is where the calculated width/height would come in. You could find the largest side of the image and work out the % increase/decrease needed to match your slider dimensions, then apply that same proportion to the other image 'side' (width or height). If you have landscape/prtrait images and you don't want to rorate them, i think it's going to look a lile ungainly howeveryou do it.